# Getting a "jQuery("a.raf_link").fancybox is not a function" error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fancybox

My URL http://math.pixelworklab.com/.

In the top right there is an "Invite a friend" link that should open a fancybox but instead loads a new page.

In firefox console I see the following and cannot seem to nail the issue...

```
TypeError: jQuery("a.raf_link").fancybox is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

'titleShow' : false

TypeError: jQuery("a.single_image").fancybox is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

jQuery("a.single_image").fancybox();
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you include jQuery file before fancybox function?

Answer (score 3):

hey I saw your site view source.. You have include jquery library twice.Remove one and it will work

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://math.pixelworklab.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>
```

and

```
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a problem because of two jQuery libraries attached. First is jquery 1.7.2 and second, stored on Google CDN, ver 1.5.2. fancybox is initialized after 1.7.2 and before 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to wrap your code (raf_script.js) in a document ready function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $("a.raf_link").fancybox({
    'titleShow'     : false
  });

  ...

});
```

The jQuery have probably not been loaded before your script loads.